# Formatting user input with .title() method

Tags: python-3.x, input, formatting

Currently, I started to learn programming with Python. Currently, I am tackling my first 'real' project.

The most problems that I seem to find, are based around formatting. I am curious if my code is written understandable. For example:

```
new_customer = input('Name? \n')
customer = new_customer.title()
```

I want to make sure all the inputs received are saved with the same format.

Is this the correct way to transform a user's input with the .title() method?

Thank you in advance, I hope that these kind of questions are accepted here!

Comment: You didn't have to use the title, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same variable:

```
newcustomer = input('Name? \n').title()
```

Is this what you mean?